# How to add GameObjects positions in a transform list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm beginner in unity an hope someone can helps me here. I have some buttons with tag `BtnCharacter` and want to find them and add their position into a transform list. I guess It might be like this:

```
public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<Transform> SaveList;
    void Start()
    {
        SaveList.Add(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("BtnCharacter").transform.position);
    }
}
```

But Debugger Shows this:

> Error CS1061: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'transform' and no extension method 'transform' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Assembly-CSharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing do u really need a generic list for it, i mean an simple array would work too. Either way these solutions should help -

**1) Using generic GameObject list**

```
public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> SaveList;
    void Start()
    {
        SaveList = new List<GameObject>(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("BtnCharacter"));
    }
}
```

**2) Using generic Transform/Vector3 list:**

In this first method for accessing position u have to add an extra `.transform.position`.

In this solution you will be able to make a generic Transform/Vector3 list to store the transforms/position, if u need to store the transforms then create a transform list else create a Vector3 list here is the code for it-

```
public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector3> SaveList;//use List<Transform> to create transform list
    void Start()
    {
        SaveList = new List<Vector3>();
        GameObject[] objectsWithTag = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("BtnCharacter");
        foreach(GameObject GO in objectsWithTag){
            SaveList.Add(GO.transform.position);//use GO.transform to add the transform in the list
        }
    }
}
```

**3) Use an array** itself, simplest i think

```
public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] SaveArray;
    void Start()
    {
        SaveArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("BtnCharacter");
    }
}
```

In the third solution if u want to store vector3 or transform array then try using the methods i used in Second solution, i could have typed the code for it too but I want you to try it yourself to get a better understanding. Hope this answer helps :)

And yes, **DOCUMENTATION EXISTS**, so googling or searching or reading the documentation would really help you trust me :)

Answer (score 3):

`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` method gets all objects with given tag as array. Your `SaveList` is a list of `Transform`, you're trying to add an array to a list.

It have to be like;

```
Transform[] array = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("BtnCharacter");
foreach(var item in array)
{
   SaveList.Add(item.transform);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this code but shows new error.

Comment: (23,23): Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to 'UnityEngine.Transform[]' (CS0029) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: `GameObject[] array = FindObjectsWithTag("BtnCharacter");` and than in the foreach do `SaveList.Add(item.transform);`

Comment: Yea sory for that, it's like @derHugo's answer.

Comment: (24,24): Error CS0103: The name 'FindObjectsWithTag' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: C'mon dude ... it's `FindGameObjectsWithTag` or `GameObject.FindGameObjects` ofcourse ;) I just made my comment to quick so I didn't write it well :D

Comment: If you mean this I:

Comment: GameObject[] array = GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("BtnCharacter");

Comment: shows another error:F:\make app\p_amirza\p_amirza\Assets\Line.cs(35,35): Error CS0117: 'UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'FindObjectsWithTag' (CS0117) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: [`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html). The documentation exists for a reason, @masihnamdar and Google knows how to search it.